# MVVM - Collection with polymorphism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

I'm trying to expose two derived types in a ListBox: OutFlight and InFlight both derive from Flight which is an abstract type.

MVVM says that I have to set a ViewModel for the ListBox' bound Model. It's not a big deal for exposig one type, but my listbox contains two derived types, and I'm looking for the best MVVM approach. Does it mean I have to set inherited ViewModels for each of the derived types? I've read somewhere ViewModel inheritance is not recommended at all... I'm sure it is a very common case

Comment: If your ViewModel contain this as a ListBox Source List<Flight> ListBoxSource; What is wrong with it?

Comment: You want a ViewModel for the items of the listbox correct?

Comment: A little sample code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a generic view model FlightViewModel that encapsulates the OutFlight and InFlight entities. So a FlightViewModel has all common properties, and is constructed based on OutFlight and InFlight entities (for example by passing them in the constructor). It could have an additional property indicating whether it's an outflight or inflight (as an enum or something).

Doing this makes FlightViewModel basically an abstraction of your concrete types OutFlight and InFlight. FlightViewModel would also only contain the properties that you actually need in your view and in the correct format so that it can easily be used by the view.

Then the view model of your view would have a collection of FlightViewModel objects.

```
public class FlightViewModel
{
    private Flight _flight;

    public FlightViewModel(OutFlight outFlight)
    {
        FlightNumber = outFlight.FlightNumber;
        FlightType = FlightType.OutFlight;
       _flight = outFlight;
    }

    public FlightViewModel(InFlight inFlight)
    {
        FlightNumber = inFlight.FlightNumber;
        FlightType = FlightType.InFlight;
       _flight = inFlight;
    }

    public int FlightNumber 
    { 
       get { return _flight.FlightNumber; }
       set { _flight.FlightNumber = value; }
    }

    public FlightType FlightType { get; set; }

    ... other properties
}
```

It's just an example of course, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways. One way is to write a ViewModel for your Flight class and fill a collection with those "FlightViewModel" objects. That ViewModel can contain all objects that inherit from "Flight". If your "InFlight" and "OutFlight" classes not so complex, I would wrap them in one ViewModel (here the "FlightViewModel").

```
public class FlightViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Flight Flight { get; set; }

    public int PropertyYouNeedForInFlight { get; set; }
    public string PropertyYouNeedForOutFlight { get; set; }
}
```

**An Other Way** is to use a collection of some base ViewModel type as the ListBox ItemsSource. That collection contains some ViewModels of type "InFlightViewModel" and some others of type "OutFlightViewModel". For your ListBox items you could write an ItemTemplateSelector that choose the correct ItemTemplate for the type of the item.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Flights { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Flights = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
        Flights.Add(new InFlightViewModel());
        Flights.Add(new OutFlightViewModel());
    }
}

public class FlightTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate InFlightTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OutFlightTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
                                                DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item.GetType() == typeof(InFlight))
            return InFlightTemplate;
        if(item.GetType() == typeof(OutFlight))
            return OutFlightTemplate

        //Throw exception or choose some random layout
        throw new Exception();
    }
 }

<local:FlightTemplateSelector
    x:Key="FlightTemplateSelector">
    <local:FlightTemplateSelector.InFlightTemplate>
       <!-- Define your layout here -->
    </local:FlightTemplateSelector.InFlightTemplate>
       <!-- Define your layout here -->
    <local:FlightTemplateSelector.OutFlightTemplate>
    </local:FlightTemplateSelector.OutFlightTemplate>
</local:FlightTemplateSelector>
```